# CSS select last child not followed by text

Tags: css, css-selectors

How can I write a CSS selector that selects the last child of an element only if it is not followed by text?

In this example

```
<button><span class="icon"></span></button>
<button><span class="icon"></span>Caption</button>
```

I want to give every icon within a button a right margin of 5px, unless nothing follows the icon within the button.

```
button .icon             {margin-right: 5px;}
button .icon:last-child  {margin-right: 0px;}
```

...does not work, because apparently the text "Caption" is not an element, so the second selector selects both icons. I want it to select only the first one. I could put "Caption" in a `<span>` but isn't there a pure CSS way?

Comment: I disagree. Invalid HTML causes unpredictable behaviour, so you could not begin to consider your issue until the HTML was corrected. To encourage help you should post the corrected HTML. However, it is probably better at this stage to post it as a new question IMO.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you can't do it unless you write the text into another element. CSS has nothing to do with text, only html elements.